# Stratifying by groups and then graphing a categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bioinformatics

I have a huge dataset in which I'm currently trying to plot certain patient categorical outcomes (paralysis no 0, yes 1) over time. Ideally I would like to first only by stratify by disease type and have that as its own series of plots. Then I'd like to stratify by location. If possible, would be really cool to stratify by Type X location.

I'm not certain, but is the first step here to convert from horizontal to vertical format of data?

An example sample of the data, several variables omitted:

| Patient | Disease Type | Location | Preoperative Paralysis | Postoperative Paralysis | Two_week Paralysis | 6 week paralysis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adeno | A | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Squamo | A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Anapla | B | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Fibrot | D | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | Adeno | E | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | Squamo | F | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | Anapla | D | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: We’re you looking for something along the lines of `aggregate( . ~ Disease_Type + Location, mydata, sum)` you can get very specific with the formula but the above sums all the columns by location and disease. the formula is of the form `y ~ x` and the `.` represents every column not named in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

To get a grid of plots with combinations of disease type x location you can use facet_grid:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = ?)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(type~location)
```

If by time you mean the pre, post, two weeks etc, you’d start with long format:

```
Data %>% pivot_longer(c(‘preop’, ‘post op’, ‘two weeks’, ‘six weeks’), names_to = ‘time’, values_to = ‘is_paralysed’) %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = is_paralysed)) + geom_bar(position = ‘fill’) + facet_grid(type~disease)
```

That should give you a set of plots showing the proportion over time of patients who are paralysed, stratified by disease type and location.